# Split a string if there is space

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose i have set of inputs that contain integers separated by space or it may contain a single integer, Is there a way to take input in single line using `raw_input().split()` if space found otherwise just `raw_input()`. **(In python 2.x)**

For example :

`Input : 1 2 3 4 5`

In this case we can use :

```
     Integers=map(int,raw_input().split(' '))
```

`Input: 2`

In this case  :

```
    Integer=int(raw_input())
```

Is there a way to combine these two in some pythonic way in one line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `split` version, it would return a single element list when only a single integer is given to `raw_input`.

```
>>> Integers=map(int,raw_input().split())
1
>>> Integers
[1]
```

Comment: +1 This ignores the special case of having a single `int` object for one integer, but that's a Good Thing.

Comment: @chepner: Yes. The following code wouldn't have to make any checks and just need to operate on the list.

Comment: I think you meant 'in the second case'

Comment: @DarinDouglass: Thanks. Fixed and removed the ambiguity.